# com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView custom dialog fill issue

Tags: android, view, android-activity, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am using com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView it's working fine but talking about view I am starting code scan after button click and it opens camera on current activity in 250x250 dimension dialog. But the issue is bar code RED line doesn't come up in center rather it moves half right to the dialog window I tried to put every possible values in XML but in vain, I am posing exl and image to show how it looks like

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="250dp" >

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/preview_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView
    android:id="@+id/viewfinder_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/result_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/result_view"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/standard_padding" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/barcode_image_view"
                android:layout_width="160dip"
                android:layout_height="160dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/half_padding"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxHeight="160dip"
                android:maxWidth="160dip"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/half_padding"
                    android:text="@string/msg_default_format"
                    android:textColor="@color/result_minor_text"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/format_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/result_minor_text" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/half_padding"
                    android:text="@string/msg_default_type"
                    android:textColor="@color/result_minor_text"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/type_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/result_minor_text" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/half_padding"
                    android:text="@string/msg_default_time"
                    android:textColor="@color/result_minor_text"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/result_minor_text" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/meta_text_view_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/half_padding"
                    android:text="@string/msg_default_meta"
                    android:textColor="@color/result_minor_text"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/meta_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/result_minor_text" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contents_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:autoLink="web"
                    android:paddingLeft="12dip"
                    android:textColor="@color/result_text"
                    android:textColorLink="@color/result_text"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contents_supplement_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:autoLink="web"
                    android:paddingLeft="12dip"
                    android:textColor="@color/result_text"
                    android:textColorLink="@color/result_text" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/result_button_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/shopper_button"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/shopper_icon"
            android:text="@string/button_google_shopper"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:text="@string/msg_default_status"
    android:textColor="@color/status_text" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

this is the image I get in result ...

[image]

I need that red LINE to be in center ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the padding attribute. Check the below code snippet.

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```

Comment: I have edited XML file to put whole file there... see that, and @MCF removing padding didn't do any good ...

Comment: Probably you might have to use RelativeLayout for the view which contain the RED Line. You can not make the inner view centered in a LinearLayouts as well. Within the RelativeLayouts you will be able to center inner views. What's the android:id which contains the RED Line ?

Comment: Ok I am gonna give it a try, the id for that view is android:id="@+id/viewfinder_view"

Comment: One clarification, When you get rid of the FrameLayout 250dp away and set to default values also you not getting the RED line in the middle ? If so this RED Line is illustrated within the onDraw() method I guess. So you might need to check that as well. And also if the RED Line comes from the code, not from the layout there is nothing you can do with modifying the XML layout . You will have to change the parameters of the RED Line parameters from the code.

Comment: Yes I did that and now it fine, but a minor issue raised, one the camera orientation is changed to opposite it's angle e.g. if I place mobile vertical it show horizontal view and vice versa and secondly the points which shows scanning of products (yellow color) started blinking on most right of the view rather than in center or as whole...

Comment: Just put the following attribute to the manifest, for the activity you are using for scanning 
android:screenOrientation="landscape"